# Auto scale page with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I'm having this basic HTML issue that, for some reason, I can't seem to fix.

I have created a vertical menu with list items.
If a list item is selected the content of that item is shown next to the menu without leaving the page. To do this I used radio buttons.

The content that is being showed is positioned absolute. This works fine as long as the content of the radiobutton isn't higher then the page height.
So the content isn't pushing the footer down as is grows.

Here is some code:
(This is a list item with content.)

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab6">
      <label for="tab6">
         <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x"></i></div>
         <div class="icon_name">Edit</div>
      </label>
      <div id="tab-content6" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">                  
          This holds a lot of content
    </div>
  </li>
```

The `div` with the class `tab-content6` is positioned absolute in order to show it next to the menu.

I tried to create a `div` around the absolute positioned div that is positioned relative but that didn't work.

Don't really know how to fix this. I wouldn't like to give it a fixed height because tabs with smaller content don't need the space.

M.

Comment: can u show your  code with css and create a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/em8wbs5x/4/ Thank you!

Comment: I have a very poor solution for now. Duplicated the class with the `position:absolute`. Renamed it and deleted the absolute positioning. Added a negative margin to place it. This must change but for now it's fine